# Copy and paste values and not formulas

Tags: vba, excel

Writing macro for the first time, I have to copy only cell values to another and which I got it working, however, I am not sure, how to copy entire column without specifying range since range may be different every time. Here, I am trying with a range which is working, but I want it to check values of cell for that column and until it finds a value copy/paste to the another column.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub CopyingCellValues()

Range("E2:E7").Copy
Range("C2:C7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple Columns copy will be...

```
Sheets("Sheet Name").Columns(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet Name").Columns(2)
```

---

Helpful info at MSDN on [Getting Started with VBA in Excel 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

---

**Edit:**

With out the formula, Try

```
Sub CopyingCellValues()
    Range("E:E").Value = _
    Range("C:C").Value
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub ValueToValue()
    [E:E].Value = [C:C].Value
End Sub
```

Comment: I did paste special since the column I am copying from is being derived from a formula, but when I only need to copy and paste value and not formula. Do I need to do Sheet Names even though its in the same sheet?

Comment: Thanks for the help!